# Streamlit distribution not found in pyinstaller executable program

Tags: python, pyinstaller, streamlit

I made a streamlit application to act as a front end for a forecasting program and then I created a pyinstaller executable file to run the application. The problem rises when I run the executable file, I get the following error: `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'streamlit' distribution was not found and is required by the application` with this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages/streamlit/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
  File "site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 476, in get_distribution
  File "site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 352, in get_provider
  File "site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 895, in require
  File "site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 781, in resolve

pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'streamlit' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[48095] Failed to execute script main
```

The file was created with the following command: pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py

This was setup on macOS Catalina with python 3.5.6 within a Conda environment

If there are any details that I may have missed that would help with this, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure it can solve your question. ( in my case it get another error lol : (  ). in `...\python38\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\__init__.py` find the variable `__version__` and change the value of it to the streamlit version ( to check it , in `.py` `import streamlit ; print(streamlit.__version_)` -> str ) ( I didn't replace the `_pkg_resources.get_distribution("streamlit").version` , just commended it )

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to add a `hook` file called `hook-streamlit.py` with the following contents

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = copy_metadata('streamlit')
```

You also need to pass the `--additional-hooks-dir` flag to your `pyinstaller` command.

If you've placed the hook file in the same directory as your python script you can specify it like so

`pyinstaller --onefile --additional-hooks-dir=. -w main.py`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It now comes to the point, where it doesn't complain about missing streamlit but when launching the exe it says:
"Failed to execute script main"